# Android: Stream a large JSON Array produced from loopj's AsyncHttpClient

Tags: java, android, json, jackson, loopj

This is my first question, I hope I didn't make any mistake..

I got a nasty long json array from from the returning value of 'onSuccess()' in this format:

```
[
    {
     "label1":"value1",
     "label2":"value2",
     "label3":"value3",
     ....
    },
    {
     "label1":"value1",
     "label2":"value2",
     "label3":"value3",
     ....
    },
    ....
]
```

when I try to convert this to String and parse it using jackson's usual 'mapper', I got the dreaded Out of memory exception. Which makes me think that I need to stream this large json instead.

I went to the example of jackson provided [here](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonStreamingApi), but the example doesn't seems to help me much

I wonder if I incapable of searching or I'm just a plain stupid in programming, but it would be much pleasure if someone could direct me to good example.

my current effort:

```
client.get(
     get_all_item_url,
     new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
       @Override
       public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseBody, Throwable e) {
                        ....
                        }


      @Override
      public void onSuccess(JSONArray response) {
           ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
           ProductModel[] productModels = null;
           try {
               productModels = mapper.readValue(response.toString(),TypeFactory.defaultInstance().constructArrayType(ProductModel.class));
               } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
               }
           ....
      }
});
```

Comment: Have you tried to save locally the JSON just to see how big it is?

Comment: 2MB. It's worth about 3000 records...

Comment: please try to reduce that response first, if you designed it

Comment: I'm afraid I can't reduce the response because that was designed by another person.

Comment: how about any parameters you can uses? Returning a 2 MB json doesn't make sense ... but if you doesn't have other way, consider to save the "Response Stream" to file and then process that file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should avoid `response.toString()` call. You can get one element  from array and parse it. It is not real streaming, but it noticeable reduce memory consumption.

Comment: I guess I'll try this as a workaround for now since the JSON is not so complicated.

Answer (score 0):

For large JSON responses you must use streaming technique. It parses the JSON data one by one:

Read this article for the details:

http://www.mkyong.com/java/jackson-streaming-api-to-read-and-write-json/